# draft js rich text editor support react native?

Tags: react-native

First, I do not speak English well.

I would like to add draft-js rich-text-editor to react-native.
However, when I browse the materials, I have difficulties because of the only data related to react.
Can not add draft-js in react-native?

- I do not want to add draft-js-render.
- I want to add a text-editor.

Comment: More details would help us to identify exactly what you are looking to do. Such as a link to the docs you have reviewed already.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'd like to add a rich-text editor to my RN app as well, but there doesn't seem to be any DraftJS support.

Answer (score 1):

The component we use in the [resume.com React Native app](http://resume.com/resume-app) is the [react-native-pell-rich-editor](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor#readme) component, which was the best free and open source component I could find for this problem. It was also the simplest and most consistent/flexible HTML parser I found. We use a draft JS editor on the main resume.com site, but this component was better for React Native.